# How do I place dynamic content into a QML component

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I'm having a lot of trouble creating extendable components in QML. There are techniques which work but what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
//Outline.qml
Rectangle {
  color: 'red'
  //Children are inserted here
}

//main.qml
Rectangle {
  ... 
  Outline {
    Text { I'm trying to inject this into the Outline component
      text: "Hi I'm the inner text!"
    }
  }
}
```

I know I can achieve this by using a `Loader` component and setting the `sourceComponent` to a `Component` instance but when I'm doing anything moderately complex (reusable dialogs for instance) my ability to write functions and reference the instance of a child component is hampered. If the component was instantiated in the same QML file the id/function relationship would be fine and I could simply reference my text fields directly.

Here's an example of the loader:

```
//Outline.qml
Rectangle {
  id : root
  color: 'red'
  property Component content;
  Loader {
    source : root.content
  }
}

//main.qml
Rectangle {
  function getData(){
     return inner.getData(); 
     //ERROR inner is undefined because it is created by the Loader instance.
  }
  ... 
  Outline {
    content: Component {
        TextField {
          id: inner
          function getData(){
            return inner.text || 'none';
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I would love an better way to handle it. I know I can build a Component directly inside the parent and achieve a top level reference, but it doesn't allow for the level of control I'm looking for. A 'static' extension of the component would be preferable in this case.

**EDIT:** here's a QML example that illustrates the problem. On click the output is:
`ReferenceError: getMe is not defined`

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Item {
    id: app
    width: 640
    height: 480

    function accessData(){
        output.text = getMe.text
    }

    Loader {
        width: parent.width
        height: 300
        sourceComponent: Component {
            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: 'yellow'

                TextField {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    id: getMe
                    placeholderText: 'Input data...'
                }
            }
        }
    }


    Button {
        id: button
        y: app.height - 50
        text: 'get data'
        onClicked: {
            accessData();
        }
    }

    Text {
        y: app.height - button.height
        id: output
        text: 'none'
    }
}
```

As you can see when you use the "loader" method the sourceComponent isn't part of the same tree (you can't access the inner data).

Comment: For your `Outline` are you looking to support any `Component` within or specific objects with a specific roles?

Comment: I am looking to support any Component/Item instance inside the Outline and have some level of control on where it lands.

Comment: Ok, so something as if you are looking to create your own type of layout class? I have an idea it's kinda long and you have to do it in C++/QML in order to access the children and get notification. If that's something you're looking for I can post an answer later when I get the solution written.

Comment: I think I'm open to any solution to the problem. I would obviously prefer a pure QML solution as that's part of why I picked the toolkit. I've updated my question with a working (failing) example.

Comment: Basically, you want to create a `QQuickItem` derived C++ class and expose it to QML. Then when you add an element in the QML inside it, your class will received the `itemChanged` signal. You can use that signal to iterate over the `children` list of your `QQuickItem` move them, updated, them, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a working solution for your **illustrative example** of the problem and later try it in your project

1. give an id to your Loader ex:" **id: yourLoader** " and the rectangle inside the loader ex: " **id: yourRect** "
2. add a String **property** to yourRect which will hold your TextField.text

   ```
   Loader { id: yourLoader
            width: parent.width
            height: 300
            sourceComponent: Component {

        Rectangle {
                    property string yourText : getMe.text
                    id: yourRect
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: 'yellow'

           TextField {
               anchors.centerIn: parent
               id: getMe
               placeholderText: 'Input data...'
           }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. we change your function accessData

   ```
    function accessData(){
                   var rect= yourLoader.item //we get yourRect from the loader 
                    output.text = rect.yourText // yourText <-- getMe.text

    }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was wondering, if the reference doesn't fail this solves the issue. I'll give this a shot with separate QML files when I'm back at the project.

Comment: This definitely solved the issue, the reference to `loader.item` was what I was missing.